# PHP добавить контакт google

Tags: php, google-contacts

хочу сделать на сайте добавление контакта в мою учетную запись google. Но что бы не было запроса разрешения на редактирование контакта. Для этого в консоле добавил Service account, а в php файле прописал следующий код

```
require_once 'src/autoload.php';

$client_email = '------@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('------.p12');

$scopes = array('googleapis.com/auth/contacts');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $client_email,
  $scopes,
  $private_key,
  'notasecret',                                 // Default P12 password
  'oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
  false,
  false
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Contacts");
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$req = new Google_Http_Request("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
$val = $client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($req);

// The contacts api only returns XML responses.
$response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";
```

контакты у меня почему то не отображаются из моей учетной записи в google, если через такую же аутентификацию добавлять контакты, то я вижу только те, которые добавил, но в учетной записи в контактах их нет. Такое ощущение что я читаю и добавляю контакты не в мою учетную запись. Не могли бы помочь с решением проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека для [Google Contacts API v3](https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api)

Небольшие примеры использования:

```
require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

    use rapidweb\googlecontacts\factories\ContactFactory;
    if (!isset($_GET['selfURL'])) {
        throw new Exception('No selfURL specified.');
    }

    $contact = ContactFactory::getBySelfURL($_GET['selfURL']);

    var_dump($contact);

    $contact->name = 'Test';
    $contact->phoneNumber = '07812363789';
    $contact->email = 'test@example.com';
    $contactAfterUpdate = ContactFactory::submitUpdates($contact);

    var_dump($contactAfterUpdate);
```